# How to use ssh client without local OS login

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, ssh-keys, automation

I have server-like machines (they are not workstations, fully automated) and I need them to be able to run a script that opens a client ssh connection (to a 3rd party server such as github), and I need it to be run in an automated fashion.

I can do this with private ssh keys, but the problem is that the machine stores the private ssh keys in a user directory with user permissions, requiring the script to be run by a user.  I have tried changing the permissions of the ssh keys, but the ssh client complains that this is insecure.

Whether I end up using ssh keys or not, I need a way to securely open a client ssh connection from boot-up without any local OS login.

I am interested in answers about how to this on Linux and/or Windows.

Comment: It would help to narrow down the stuff if you specify which SSH client you want to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, you can use the Task Scheduler to make an application run as a certain user:

[image]

Notice under security options.  You'd check th box for "Run whether user is logged on or not" and then "Chang User or Group" and select the user that set it up.  It will ask for their password.

Comment: This seems like it should work in theory.  I'm getting the error "A specified logon session does not exist", but that seems like it may be specific to our AD set-up here, and may not be related to the original question.

Comment: @cowlinator- do you limit who can log onto the machine (such as only certain AD accounts)?

Comment: Yes, but the user I used is on the whitelist

Comment: Check out this Technet article, sounds like this could be it: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/04/18/task-scheduler-error-a-specified-logon-session-does-not-exist/

Comment: Thank you Allen.  Unfortunately, I don't seem to have permission to follow the instructions in that article, probably due to Group Policy. :(

Answer (score 1):

> I can do this with private ssh keys, but the problem is that the machine stores the private ssh keys in a user directory with user permissions, requiring the script to be run by a user.

Not true. Check your SSH client's documentation on how to use a private key file stored in arbitrary location in your file-system.

For OpenSSH check [ssh_config(5) - IdentityFile](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#IdentityFile)

Furthermore any automated process runs as a certain user in any OS. So simply make sure ownership and permissions of the private key file are correctly set for this service user / tool account or whatever you call it.

Comment: You are correct, the ssh key can be stored in any arbitrary location.  My mistake.  However, I still have the problem that I can't have a private ssh key that has read permission for all users on the machine, as that is insecure.

Comment: Edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense.  I was assuming that a script in `/etc/init.d/` will run as root or something.